# C++ vector of vector of abstract class

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

for a simple chess game I want to create a 2D vector of a vector of (chess) pieces. So my class looks like

```
class board {
    private:
        int width, height; //dimensions
        vector<vector<piece> > pieces2D;

    public:
        board(int w=8, int h=8) 
        {
            width = w; height = h;
            vector<vector<piece>> pieces2D(w, vector<piece>(h, 0));
        }
```

Where piece is an abstract class so I cant use an array. But I cant create the pieces2D in the constructor with the default size 8x8. What is missing? I also appreciate other solutions to store the 64 (abstract) pieces.

Comment: You can use a `vector<vector<std::unique_ptr<piece>> > pieces2D;` instead.

Comment: "abstract" is synonym for "cannot create instances of that class" so you cannot have `piece` instances in the vector only pointers (or references)

Comment: On a secondary issue, in the constructor `vector<vector<piece>> pieces2D(w, vector<piece>(h, 0));` defines a *new* and *distinct* and *local* variable named `pieces2D`. It's totally unrelated to the member variable with the same name. I suggest you take some time to research *constructor initializer lists*.

Comment: Despite the syntactic similarities, C++ is very unlike Java and C# in very fundamental ways.

Answer (score 2):

You're unable to instantiate an abstract class - you're thereby unable to construct a vector containing an abstract type.

The solution here is to store a vector of pointers:
`vector<vector<std::unique_ptr<piece>>>`

Comment: `std::array` might be a better choice

Comment: @JamesPicone Board size seems to be configurable at runtime

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot use an abstract class as a template to std::array, std::vector or any other STL container class. Use a std::unique_ptr or a std::shared_ptr to store pointers to objects if you want to use polymorphism.

The initialization of the pieces2D member could be done

```
class board {
  private:
    int width, height; //dimensions
    vector<vector<piece> > pieces2D;

  public:
    board(int w=8, int h=8) 
      : pieces2D(w, vector<piece>(h, 0))
    {
        width = w; height = h;
    }
};
```

But it will not work without replacing piece by std::shared_ptr. IMHO it is also better to use a flat (one dimensional) array for the pieces because that way you only have one heap block to manage. You could use an () operator (or a simple member function) to access the pieces by row and column:

```
class Board
{
private:
   int width, height;
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>> pieces;

public:
   Board(int width_, int height_)
      : width(width_),
      height(height_),
      pieces(width_ * height_)
   {}

   std::shared_ptr<Piece>& operator()(int row, int col)
   {
      return pieces[row*width+col];
   }
};
```

and to use it:

```
Board board(8, 8);
board(1, 2) = std::make_shared<PawnPiece>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the class attribute pieces2D is incorrect.

What you are trying to do is to initialize the class attribute, but what you effectively do is initializing an object local to the constructor which is named pieces2D and will be destroyed when the program goes out of the constructor scope.

In addition you can't instantiate a vector of abstract objects, because no object can be instantiated from an abstract class.
But you can instantiate a vector of pointers to abstract objects, and assign to it pointers to concrete objects deriving from the base abstract class.

What you look for is probably initialization list for pieces2D.

Like :

```
class board {
private:
    int width, height; //dimensions
    vector<vector<piece*> > pieces2D;

public:
    board(int w=8, int h=8): pieces2D(w, vector<piece*>(h, 0))
    {
        width = w; height = h;
    }
}
```

Comment: you adress one problem in the code, but you miss to answer the actual question and if `piece` is abstract your example wont compile

Comment: also why dont you use the initializer list for `width` and `height` ?

Comment: actually `width` and `heigth` are redundant and should be removed alltogether

Comment: Indeed for the actual question about piece being abstract, I'm correcting it.
I didn't changed anything not related to the question, so I didn't changed for width and height. I can't assume their redundancy, maybe the code excerpt shown is partial or simplified.

Comment: with redundant i didnt mean that in OPs example both are `8`, but I meant that a vector already knows its size and storing the size seperately requires unnecessary bookkeeping and is a source of errors